# Have clang-format align one-line function definitions

Tags: c++, clang-format

I know it is possible to align variable definitions and affectations with `clang-format`, using `AlignConsecutiveAssignments` and `AlignConsecutiveDeclarations` to get something like

```
int          a_value;
unsigned int another_value;
float        a_last_value;

a_value       = 2;
another_value = 3;
a_last_value  = 42.0f;

// Or both at the same time    
int          a_value       = 2;
unsigned int another_value = 3;
float        a_last_value  = 42.0f;
```

Now, is there any way to do a similar stuff with one-line functions / methods (one-lined using `AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine` for example) ? I mean to get something like

```
void SetPositions(const vec3_array& p) { m_Data.Positions = p; }
void SetUVs(const vec2_array& u)       { m_Data.UVs = u; }
void SetNormals(const vec3_array& n)   { m_Data.Normals = n; }
void SetIndices(const UIntArray& i)    { m_Data.Indices = i; }
```

or maybe even

```
void SetPositions(const vec3_array& p) { m_Data.Positions = p; }
void SetUVs      (const vec2_array& u) { m_Data.UVs = u; }
void SetNormals  (const vec3_array& n) { m_Data.Normals = n; }
void SetIndices  (const UIntArray& i)  { m_Data.Indices = i; }
```

instead of

```
void SetPositions (const vec3_array& p) { m_Data.Positions = p; }
void SetUVs(const vec2_array& u) { m_Data.UVs = u; }
void SetNormals(const vec3_array& n) { m_Data.Normals = n; }
void SetIndices(const UIntArray& i) { m_Data.Indices = i; }
```

Comment: Are you looking for `AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine`?

Comment: I am already using `AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine`, this leads to the last example code. I edit the question to reflect your comment though

Comment: Ah, Ok I misunderstood

Comment: I don't think there is. You could submit a feature request.

Comment: I will do this then, thanks for the input

Comment: It is not possible with clang format but I use this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66417895/format-function-declaration-clang-format

Comment: Well, mixing between tools is not an option for me. Neither making a particular editor for everyone in the team mandatory actually :)

Comment: I put `AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine` fully to the end of the .clang-format file, it seems to fix my problem.. I hope for you as well.

Comment: @cmourglia Have you already raised a feature request? This is an useful requirement