# format function declaration Clang-format

Tags: c++, clang-format

I want to format my code like this :

all parenthesis MUST BE align (cause of my company coding rules :))

```
bool         Start   (void);
void         Stop    (void);
void         Run     (void);
```

all I have seen format it like this :

```
bool         Start(void);
void         Stop(void);
void         Run(void);
```

all function names are aligned but not the parenthesis

have you a tips to do that with Clang-format extensions ? (I use clang V12)

thank you !

Comment: Please don't post images of code

Comment: Formatting code is your IDE's task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, to align all parenthesis I have download code alignment in VScode and I applied alignment by ( in all function declaration.